# Why sometimes a variable is dereferenced in match?

Tags: syntax, rust, pattern-matching

It's very common to see a variable being dereferenced inside match expression. Rust's `libcore` uses this in some functions:

```
impl<T> Option<T> {
    pub fn is_some(&self) -> bool {
        match *self {
                Some(_) => true,
                None => false,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When should we use it and when we shouldn't? Does this have memory or performance penality?

Comment: Mostly a matter of style. No impact on memory or performance, once it's been through the optimiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match patterns must be the same type as the expression. If the expression is a reference then the patterns must also match against references.

In a method that takes `&self` (a reference), this:

```
match self {
    &Some(_) => true,
    &None => false,
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
match *self {
    Some(_) => true,
    None => false,
}
```

There is no performance difference; they should end up compiling to the same thing ([proof](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/9x6a1b)).

The second one is considered better style because it uses fewer characters, and  makes the patterns less noisy and repetitive. With default settings, Clippy will warn you if you do the first one.

In a lot of cases, including this one, you can omit the references in the patterns altogether:

```
match self {
    Some(_) => true,
    None => false,
}
```

This is a kind of syntactic sugar, where the `&`s are automatically added in unambiguous cases. I can't tell you exactly when this is allowed, but the compiler certainly will tell you when it's not! ;) In practice, I tend to write `match` statements like this, without explicit references, and then fix it up if the compiler complains.

Comment: Why we shouldn't  simply write `Some(_)` or `None` in your second example?

Comment: @IsaacFerreira You're talking about "match ergonomics" which lets the compiler automatically add `&`s and `ref`s inside patterns to make things work. It's not 100% perfect, but you're right, it would work in this case. However whether it makes the code *better* is a matter of opinion.

Comment: ... sorry, that's called the [default binding mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#binding-modes) now rather than "match ergonomics"... it can be difficult to keep up with the latest. Whatever you call it, it didn't exist when PeterHall and I learned Rust ;-)

Comment: @trentcl true! A lot of the ergonomic improvements over the years make code simpler and cleaner, but also make it harder to explain exactly how things actually work. For example, my mental model for lifetimes is still basically lexical - but with a handful of special cases which I know _also_ work.